# Passing strings from arrays with a requirement

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I'm pretty much new to Javascript so this isn't a question of efficiency, more just a question of possibility!

```
var experience = 156;

var titleData = [
  {"Duke" 
if (0 < experience < 101)},
  {"King" 
if (100 < experience < 201)},
  {"Emperor"
if (300 < experience < 301)}
];

return(titleData)
```

I'm creating a very small and simple game using html and javascript and have been stuck at this point for close to two hours after much google searching. I'm trying to use this array to store a list of possible titles that would be passed onto the html to be used as a title before the person's name and have paired down what I am working on into this much simpler and shorter example.

I want to use the variable 'experience' in order to return a specific string, such as Duke or Emperor from the array and then eventually pass that on with getElementById and inputting that directly on the webpage. So that when the player gains more experience, the title automatically updates. I know I'll have to use a for loop at some point, but trying to figure out exactly what needed to go into that proved to be too much of a hair-puller.

I know I am probably doing this VERY wrong, but this is my first foray into trying to use arrays in this way. I'm not married to the idea of an array or the way that I have tried to set it up, so if I am doing this in the completely most roundabout way, let me know. I hope I was able to communicate the essence of what I'm trying to accomplish, even if my code isn't clear.

Comment: that is not valid javascript - use developer tools console in your browser to see your errors

Comment: You just invented the switch statement.

Comment: Hahaha I did? Well, I'll take that as a compliment I suppose. (even though I know my work isn't compliment-worthy hahaha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roberrrt already mentioned, your syntax is not valid, you can not use `if` statements inside an object or array declaration.

---

One of many possible approaches would be to first declare your different titles in an array, defining the title and their min/max experience boundaries. This data can then also be moved e.g. to a separate config file to better compartementalize your code.

After that, it is only a matter of going through the different titles and checking whether the player fulfills the experience requirements:

```js
var experience = 156;
var titleData = [];

var titles = [{
  name: "Duke",
  min: 0,
  max: 101
}, {
  name: "King",
  min: 100,
  max: 201
}, {
  name: "Emperor",
  min: 300,
  max: 301
}, {
  name: "Khal",
  min: 120,
  max: 160
}];

for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  if (titles[i].min < experience && titles[i].max > experience) {
    titleData.push(titles[i].name);
  }
}

console.log(titleData); // ["King", "Khal"]
```

---

In order to make the experience boundaries even more flexible, you could even define a function for each of the titles, defining the condition:

```js
    var experience = 1000000;
    var titleData = [];

    var titles = [{
      name: "Oddball",
      condition: function(exp) {
        return (exp % 2) == 0; // Exp. multiple of 2?
      }
    }, {
      name: "Supreme Leader",
      condition: function(exp) {
        return exp > Math.pow(2, 10); // Exp. greater than the 10th power of 2?
      }
    }];

    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      if (titles[i].condition(experience)) {
        titleData.push(titles[i].name);
      }
    }

    console.log(titleData); // ["Oddball", "Supreme Leader"]
```

Comment: This is a way more robust approach to build your application on, if possible, i'd use this way of setting up your game.

Comment: Awesome Answer :)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I was thinking of setting up an exponential increase in experience cost for the next title but didn't want to complicate this question too much, (it's a silly little idle game). I'm assuming I could replace that min-max cost data set in the array for something like the initial cost raised to a certain power? I know how many titles I'm going to have so I can enter the actual exponents in manually.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. You can add as much flexibility to the problem as needed. However note that it is usually a good idea to keep the flexibility and with that the complexity as small as possible to avoid problems. If you want to define fixed exp. boundaries that are known beforehand, it may be a good idea to simply calculate them beforehand and hard-code them into your config instead of calculating them at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. I know it would be a good learning experience to try and calculate the experience cost dynamically, but practically, just hard coding it in seems like a good idea haha. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, you're declaring an array which holds data, you cannot use logic inside of that declaration. The correct way is to declare the titles, and push them inside the array.

```
// Setting the current experience a player has
var experience = 156;

// Defining a function that returns the title, based upon the experience
function getTitle(experience) {

    // List all options, based on the experience
    if(experience < 101) {
        // Return basically means 'give back this value as function output'
        return "Duke";
    }
    else if(experienec < 201) {
        return "King";
    }
    else if(experience < 301) {
        return "Emperor";
    }
    else {
        return "Too high!";
    }

}

// Declaring the players title, by calling the getTitle() function, 
// with the experience as a parameter.
var title = getTitle(experience);
```

EDIT: As @Brian stated, this could be more elegant using the `switch` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
var level = 1;

switch (level) {
    case 1:
        return "Duke";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "King";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "Emperor";
        break;
    default:
        return "Too high!";
}
```

Comment: could also try switch there

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

I think I've just been going at it for so long with the mentality of it being an array that I completely tunnel visioned doing it any other way.

Comment: Yeah, i've added the option of using a `switch` it's just that I dislike the idea of logical operators inside a switch statement.

Comment: Logical operations inside switch will not work as expected. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/u6ryjk7p/. That is a wrong suggestion to make as an answer. It will compare experience with the result in the fiddle.

Comment: I knew something was wrong, i'll edit the code so at least it's not broken.

Comment: You should probably not recommend switch case here at all, its not suitable for this scenario. But otherwise your answer was in the right direction.

Comment: It's still a valuable asset to use in simular (but not the same) scenarios, so i'll leave it in for the original poster to take lesson from it.

Answer (score 0):

An array cannot have if inside it. If you need to do this using an array, this is one way of doing it:

```
var titleData = [];
if (0 < experience < 101) {
  titleData.push("Duke");
} else if (100 < experience < 201) {
  titleData.push("King")
} 
...
return(titleData)
```

But If its just going to be a string, you can also do:

```
function (experience) {
    var titleData = "";
    if (0 < experience < 101) {
      titleData = "Duke";
    } else if (100 < experience < 201) {
      titleData = "King";
    }
    ...
    return(titleData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something almost like you want, using javascript ternary statement

```
condition ? value-when-true : value-when-false;
```

> see MDN documentation for [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

e.g.

```
var titleData = [ experience < 0 ? "peasant" : experience < 101 ? "Duke" : experience < 201 ? "king" : experience < 301 ? "Emperor" : "uber"]
```

Added peasant, what happens under 0 ? ;)
Added uber, what happens above 301:?

Comment: What is the question mark? I'm not familiar with that usage.

Comment: I've added a bit of an explanation - hang on- will add a documentation link

Comment: I personally find the ternary structure a one-way ticket to obfuscated and unreadable code, especially in this context.

Comment: @Roberrrt - I disagree with your opinion but I'll defend to the death your right to voice it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the titles for anything else, just have a function return the right one given the experience:

```
function titleGivenExperience(experience) {
    if (experience <= 100) return "Duke";
    if (experience <= 200) return "King";
    return "Emperor";
}

var title = titleGivenExperience(120);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var titleData =[];
var experience = 156;
if(0 < experience < 101)
{
          var data = "Duke";
          titleData.push(data);  
}
if(100 < experience < 201)
{
          var data = "King";
          titleData.push(data);  
}
if(300 < experience < 301)
{
          var data = "Emperor";
          titleData.push(data);  
}
return(titleData);
```

Hope this will work,